# VBA: Why can't I use two VLookUps in a row?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use two VLookUps in a row in my macro. The macro counts the IDs in column A and C, searches for the ID description in another table (same sheet and ranges from column F to M -> F = IDs, H = ID description) and continues this search until the count is reached and inserts them in column B and D.

Unfortunately, I get a

> run time error 1004

when using the second VLookUp. First one works fine and it's exactly the same as in the first one I am just referring to different cells.

Picture reference of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Does anyone know what causes this problem?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim shA As Worksheet
Set shA = Worksheets(Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
With shA

 For i = 4 To .Range("A4", .Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 3
        .Cells(i, 2) = .Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(i, 1), .Range("F:M"), 3, False)
 Next i 

 For i = 4 To .Range("C4", .Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 3
        .Cells(i, 4) = .Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(i, 3), .Range("F:M"), 3, False)
 Next i

End With
```

Comment: The error means that your lookup value is not found. From the image it looks like one set of numbers (that works) is stored as text, and the other is stored as actual numbers.

Comment: Looked it up. Both are stored as "Standard".

Comment: The cell format is not necessarily indicative of how it is stored. Unless you have manually aligned one column left and one right, the two columns are not stored the same way judging by your picture, and the error you are receiving. Try using `CStr(.Cells(i, 3))` as the lookup value. If that works, my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace `Integer` with `Long` and try again.
In VBA `Integer` is

from ***-2^15 to 2^15-1*** or

from ***-32768 to 32767***

Thus, if you use it in Excel and it refers numbers which are outside this range, you get an error. In general, you have some other errors as well. Try this and make sure that you have the correct `ActiveSheet` selected (I have done it for easy, you may change it later):

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim i As Long

    Dim shA As Worksheet
    Set shA = ActiveSheet

    With shA
        For i = 4 To .Range("A4", .Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 3
            .Cells(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 1), .Range("F:M"), 3, False)
        Next i
        For i = 4 To .Range("C4", .Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 3
            .Cells(i, 4) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 3), .Range("F:M"), 3, False)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Thus, in general:

- Do not use `On Error Resume Next`, because it is a bit tough.
- When you use `With Worksheets("someName")`, then make sure that every time you put a dot `.`, the child is a real child of the `with-Parent`. In your case `.Application` is not a child of `Worksheets()`
- Do not use `Integer`, but `Long`

Comment: Error is still appearing.

Comment: @Fiops  - you are probably refering to the wrong parent. Can you give the `With - End With` code? + Do you have by any change `On Error Resume Next` somewhere?

Comment: Added the `With - End With` code. Yes I do have a `On Error Resume Next` build in as well as a `On Error GoTo 0`.

Comment: Removed the `On Error Resume Next` and the dot `.` before `Application` but I still get the error.

Comment: It works now but I used the code I posted. No idea why it works now. I have changed nothing.